# Where should I ask about Apple's cryptography export compliance setting?

Tags: discussion, scope

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973567/what-constitutes-encryption-for-the-purpose-of-export-compliance-e-g-in-app#10974299) on SO, but it was closed as off-topic.

I'd like clarification on my particular scenario (no custom network call, just CloudKit/iCloud Drive).

Comment: Aha, okay. Thank you. Though, again, wasn't looking for justification on why, just a possible solution. I think the correct answer is: `Ask Apple.`.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is off topic.  It's a policy of a third party website that can change at any time.  We can't give you an authoritative answer, and even if we could it could be changed tomorrow.  If you really need to know, contact Apple.

Comment: Thank you. (Wasn't really looking for a justification for it being off-topic on SO, just wanted to be pointed in the right direction for an answer, if it were available.)